# How to change image of a button on click?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, imagebutton

I have an array of bitmaps `ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<>(3)` and need to change the image of a ImageButton in every click, first  `images(0)` then, after I click `image(1)` and finally `image(2)`.

For this I am using `myImageButton.setImageBitmap(images.get(0))` for the first image, how do I change to the next and then to the third?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
int currentPos = 0;
onclick(){
 currentPos = (currentPos+1)%(images.size()-1)
 myImageButton.setImageBitmap(images.get(currentPos))
}
```

Comment: I did it like this, but didn't work

currentPos = 0;
myImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPos = currentPos%(images.size()-1);
                myImageButton.setImageBitmap(images.get(currentPos));
            }
        });

Comment: Humm, now it changes from 1st to 2nd image and comes back, not to 3rd.

Comment: I made currentPos=(currentPos+1)%(images.size()) and worked! Thanks! (can't upvote your answer, I'm new here)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
int currentPos = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        myImageButton.setImageBitmap(images.get(0))
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    currentPos++;
    if(currentPos == 2){
        // if the imagebutton has the bitmap from position 2, you can do what you want
        //example:
        currentPos = 0;// so you have the first Bitmap you had when the user didn't click on the ImageButton
    }
    myImageButton.setImageBitmap(images.get(currentPos));
}
```